# Two One-To-One relationships to same Entity type in Entity Framework Core 1.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core, one-to-one

We have a generic Tagging system that does a form of two-way tagging for binding entities together (think a Customer can be tagged with a Letter, and that Letter will also get a tag back to the Customer). Meaning that once we tag "one way", we also tag "the other way". These two tags are stored in an **EntityConnection** - so that table/entity has two connections to the same **EntityTag** table/entity - *SideA* and *SideB*.

These entities exist across different micro services and databases, so we can't have a direct EF relationship between the various types of entities - hence this generic solution.

The relationship is represented by the following two classes:

```
public class EntityConnection : EntityBase
{
    public Guid SideBId { get; set; }
    public Guid SideAId { get; set; }

   public EntityTag SideA { get; set; }

   public EntityTag SideB { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTag : EntityBase
{
    public virtual EntityConnection ParentConnection { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentConnectionId { get; set; }

    public Guid EntityId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DisplayTitle { get; set; }

    public EntityTag GetOtherSide()
    {
        if (ParentConnection.SideA.Id != EntityId)
        {
            // Side A is other side - return it
            return ParentConnection.SideA;
        }
        else
        {
            return ParentConnection.SideB;
        }
    }
}
```

The relationships are modelled in the DbContext like so:

```
private void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityTag> obj)
{
   obj.HasIndex(x => new {x.Type, x.EntityId});

}

private void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EntityConnection> obj)
{
   obj.HasOne(x => x.SideA)
      .WithOne(x => x.ParentConnection)
      .HasForeignKey<EntityConnection>(x => x.SideAId).IsRequired()
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

   obj.HasOne(x => x.SideB)
      .WithOne(x => x.ParentConnection)
      .HasForeignKey<EntityConnection>(x => x.SideBId).IsRequired()
      .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
   }
}
```

When I try adding a migration, I get this error message:

> Cannot create a relationship between 'EntityTag.ParentConnection' and 'EntityConnection.SideB', because there already is a relationship between 'EntityTag.ParentConnection' and 'EntityConnection.SideA'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.

Now, I understand the error message (I think). But it doesn't make sense to me. Every EntityTag will only be connected to one EntityConnection through it's ParentConnection property, and I thought that specifying the foreign keys like we have in the DbContext would solve this.

Can anybody help me progress further here?